# replace single quote in middle of string using regex

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, string

Have a string:

```
stringName= "'john's example'"
```

Need to do a `string.replace` to remove the single quote in the middle of the string, not the first and last otherwise will break my javascript

have tried `stringName.replace("/.'./","")` to replace only the single quote in the middle of the string but does not work

Help is very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `(^'|'$)|'` as matching regular expression:

```js
stringName = "'john's e'xam'ple'";
console.log(
  stringName.replace(/(^'|'$)|'/g, '$1')
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! :)
quick question, i am doing it in .net and the string is fixed with only 1 single quote and you have doubled the quotes up .. any way of getting around this? to just replace that 1 single quote with a space

Comment: Hi, I didn't get you. Please elaborate on issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry i am doing it in .net
So my string is: dim example as string = " 'john's example' "
 Dim regex As String = example.Replace("(^'|'$)|'", "")
        Response.Write(regex)

would this not work? the string is fixed to one single quote in the middle and cant be changed

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you aren't doing a regex replace, you are replacing a string which looks like `/.'./` (because of the `"` in the first argument). Secondly, the regex you're doing is only going to be looking for a single character (`.`) then a single quote, then another character. What you might want to do is something like `stringName.replace(/(.+)'(.+)/, "$1$2")`

Comment: I would say to use revo's answer over this

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`, `join` after stripping of first and last character

```
var f1 = (str) => str.charAt(0) + str.split("'").join("") + str.slice(-1);

f1( "'john's exa''mp'le'" ); //'johns example'
```

Comment: How about `"'john's exa''mp'le'"`?

Comment: @revo Didn't thought of it, fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.